# cloud carousel bringToFront: true with links

Tags: jquery

I have a cloud carousel installed on my web site: http://dev.webcoder.kz/page/fashion-autumn-2013

```
$("#cloud").CloudCarousel(
  {
    xPos: 480,
    yPos: 50,
    buttonLeft: $("#left-but"),
    buttonRight: $("#right-but"),
    altBox: $("#alt-text"),
    titleBox: $("#title-text")
  }
);
```

When you click on every image - this image is shown in original in a colorbox. It's ok.

I want to use `bringToFront: true` option with this carousel.
I mean, show colorbox with image originals size only when you click on a front image!
When you click on not front images they just scroll and become a main image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. Here is a solution to modify the carousel.js

```
$(container).find("a").click(function(event){
            if($(this).index()!=$(container).data("cloudcarousel").frontIndex){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```